# Finland: Criteria to judge a drawn picture child pornography (and legality of virtual child pornography in general)

Tags: pornography, finland

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_status_of_drawn_pornography_depicting_minors#Finland) article on Wikipedia (and [this](https://www.finlex.fi/en/laki/kaannokset/1889/en18890039.pdf) for the source):

> [...] and realistic, if it **resembles in a misleading manner a picture or a visual recording produced through photography or in another corresponding manner of a situation** in which a child is the object of sexually offensive conduct.

I have trouble interpreting that sentence, especially the part in bold. If I understand correctly, the only criteria to make the drawing illegal is that the drawing looks very similar to (and can be mistaken for) a real photo, and it can be paraphrased like this?

> [...] if it resembles, in a misleading manner (or in another corresponding manner), a picture or a visual recording produced through photography of a situation [...]

And in general, what is the official stance on the legality of drawn child pornography (the type that can be encountered in some Japanese material like hentai and visual novels) in Finland, and is there any other criteria like *obscenity* in the US?

Answer (score 1):

A believe that "in another corresponding manner" modifies "produced through photography" not "misleading", That is, the sentence fragment  may be paraphrased as:L

> if it so resembles a photograph or an image or video produced through photography, or produced by some similar method, so that it could mislead a person into believing that it is a photograph or video, and if such image or video is of a situation in which a child is the object of sexually offensive conduct.

The above does not seem to include most drawings, but I cannot speak to the official Finnish attitude to drawings of such situations, nor to what other laws there may be on child porn in Finland.